# Working with multiple images in a clockkit complication

Tags: image, watchos, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I'm trying to put together a complication for my app, I'd like to have it potentially display different images depending on the content of the complication entry but am not sure how best to handle this.

I've got a complication group added to my watch extensions asset catalogue but it only seems to have slots for a single icon in multiple versions, for complication family and device size. I'm presuming this one that is linked to my watch's complication group is only for use by placeholder content, but then as you construct this template yourself I'm not sure why it has this project setting association with a group.

As I would like to add around 10-15 icons to choose from do I need to add multiple complication image sets to my watch app assets? Last years WWDC video on creating complications was early and had them working with images directly instead of image sets, but for the different watch sizes etc I'm presuming image sets are the preferred way to go about this.

Thanks for your help in advance, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it seems I'm able to work with normal images that are shared in my app between my iOS app, today widget and watch app. They work ok at the moment, but I'm not sure if they're the right way to go about it as they're definitely not the right size for complications being 30,60, and 90 pixels depending on the scale they're targeting. Still not entirely sure what the complication set is for in the assets as they don't seem to match the image size outlined in the apple guidelines for complications